# How to properly say "I have to study" or "I need to study"?

Tags: grammaire

I am stuck in a situtation where I google the methods of saying such sentence. I end up finding two possible most common solutions for this, which would be

> Je avoir à étude

and

> Je dois étudier.

I'm really new to French, have been searching for the basics all around but couldn't find a definite answer yet.

Comment: seule la seconde proposition **je dois étudier** est correcte

Comment: I'm surprised "Je avoir à étude" shows as a common solution at all as it is simply a very word-to-word but also very wrong translation of "I have to study"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- “I have to study” => Je dois étudier. *or* J'ai à étudier.
- “I need to study” => J'ai besoin d'étudier.

"Je avoir à étude" corresponds to nothing<sup>1</sup> (2 errors); "je" is a personal pronoun, therefore there must be a conjugated verb form after it, never an infinitive.
It is apparent that the verb in question is "avoir" when its sens is "have to"; "to" is rendered by "à", but just as in English that must be followed by an infinitive, never a noun: "I have to go. => J'ai à m'en aller.".

<sup>1</sup><sub>More exactly, it is meaningless</sub>

Comment: "Je avoir à étude" does correspond to something-- it corresponds to "I to have to a study," approximately.

Comment: Well, yes, literally, it corresponds  "I to have to the study" and that is nothing meaningful! Do you have something meaningful in mind? Probably not , I guess it' just a matter of absoluteness…

Answer (score 2):

In addition to *je dois étudier*, another common and idiomatic way to say it is :

> Il faut que j'étudie.

Comment: What about *il me faut étudier*?

Comment: @iBug It's correct but quite formal.

Comment: Ça ne serait pas si formel que l'on puisse croire d'après moi ; voyons par exemple ceci : « Il me faut faire des drôles d'efforts pour m'intéresser aux copains. Facilement je les perdrais de vue. Je suis préoccupé (CÉLINE, Mort à crédit) ». Il n'y a rien de plus familier que « copain ».

Comment: @LPH Non. La forme *il me faut + infinitif* est de registre soutenu (même pour [l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/cecile-c-etats-unis)), sauf parfois encore dans le midi sous l'influence d'un substrat occitan (*Me fau anar a Bordeu* : Il faut que j'aille à Bordeaux). Voir https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/je-dois-il-me-faut-il-faut-que-je.1135741/#post-14321557 or

Comment: Oui, **formel ici**, à l'Académie, c'est à dire de par une certaine littérature dominante, et dans le parler du nord, et **pas formel ailleurs**, c'est à dire dans le midi et selon le point de vue de Céline; après avoir été confronté à tout cela, au français en somme, on a « formel et pas formel ».

Comment: @LPH *Mi fas caga*... Tu sais ce que veut dire *quite* en anglais ?

Comment: Ces problèmes de langue vous embêtent parfois ? Il faut le reconnaitre, ils constituent souvent des labyrinthes inextricables, désespérants… des mosaiques à en perdre la tête… « quite » ici doit être « passablement, assez », ce n'est pas « très formel », je sais cela ;

Comment: @LPH Ce ne sont pas les problèmes de langues qui m'embêtent. Tu fais cependant preuve de lucidité en écrivant *à en perdre la tête*, c'est exactement de ça qu'il s'agit...

Answer (score 1):

Additionally,

> J'ai besoin d'étudier

is also common, but maybe less so.

> Je avoir a etude

is plain unintelligible. A better phrase would be

> Je dois étudier

as others have stated.

"Apprendre" can sometimes be substituted here, as long as "to learn" would be equivalent.